# Python 3 taking user input to access dictionary in another file

Tags: python, dictionary, input

I want to take the users input (current_input) and use it to access a dictionary called (john) in a file called (john.py).  If the user inputs john, I want the for statement to check john.john and print out the keys (x) and the attributes (john.john[x]).  Any ideas?

```
import john
current_fugitive = input("Please enter the name of the fugitive: ")
if current_fugitive =="john":
    for x in current_fugitive.current_fugitive:
        print(x, current_fugitive.current_fugitive[x])
```

(EDIT)
The original code that worked:

```
if current_fugitive =="john":
for x in john.john::
    print(x, john.john[x])
```

Comment: What's wrong with the above code?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar everything. The first error thrown is probably `AttributeError` since he's trying to access `"john".current_fugitive`.

Comment: for x in current_fugitive.current_fugitive:                                                                                                
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'current_fugitive'

Comment: The only thing wrong here is using the input's variable in my for statement and the printing of the info in the dictionary..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

---

```
import john

def printDict(d):
    # d can be an empty dict
    for k in d:
        print(k, d[k])

tip = "Please enter the name of the fugitive: "
user_input = input(tip)
d = getattr(john, user_input, None)

if (type(d) is dict):   
    printDict(d)
else:
    print("Not a dict or doesn't exist")
```

Comment: There are non-obvious problems with this code beyond the fact that it's promoting a bad code architecture. PEP8, for one (2-space indents? pshaw.) but more pressingly what if `getattr(john, current)` is an empty dict? Or a `False`, or `0`? All of that goes down the code path that says the variable doesn't exist. The quick fix is `if d is None: print(...)`, but the real solution is "don't do this."

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was just coding in javaScript and forgot to set the auto ident of my editor into 4 spaces.Will the updated version be better?  @AdamSmith

Comment: So if I used multiple fugatives the 
    d = getattr(john, user_input, None)
wouldn't work correctly if I had, say a chad and ricky as well.

Comment: @Jason If you want mutiple fugatives，I think you could write a function to get all fugatives you need.Or maybe implement it by another way.Basically this is not a good way to load data from another files.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to do this. This is a common mistake beginners make where you assign *meaning* to your variable names. Don't do that -- your *values* have meaning, but your variable names should be good, descriptive names that are clear to the programmer, but mean nothing to the program.

Most likely, `john.py` should be `john.json` and you should do:

```
from pathlib import Path
import json

fugitives = {}

for fugitive_json in Path(__file__).glob("*.json"):
    # find all the *.json files that are sibling to the current file
    with fugitive_json.open() as f:
        new_fugitive = json.load(f)
        fugitives[fugitive_json.stem] = new_fugitive
        # Path("path/to/john.json").stem == "john"

user_input = input("Which fugitive? ")
try:
    fugitive = fugitives[user_input]
except KeyError:
    # what do you do when the user enters a bad name?
    # maybe...
    raise
```

Comment: This code looks completely foreign to me as I am just learning Python 3.  Maybe what I want to do with it is a bit beyond my scope as a beginner.

Comment: @Jason if you point out where you don't understand the code, I can help. I left comments at the particularly hard to "grok" parts.